# Is is possible to increase the maximum upload size on wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, image, wordpress, image-processing

Basicaly I'd like to find a way to increase the maximum upload size, I'm only talking about wordpress because it happens to be the platform Im working on but what I need is to find a way to go around php setting on the server as wordpress seems to use those setting as default.
Note that I'm only looking at uploading pictures, no other sort of files.

I have found several pages on google explaining either how to edit wordpress setting (in my case this is not something that would work), or changing the php setting on the server side, and I simply cannot do that.

I have thought of a few ways to reach this goal but don't know where to start as I'm not that good in picture processing. I was thinking about evaluating the picture size and dividing it into several files (is it something do-able in js ?), then upload them onto the server and assemble them from there in php (that I can do).

Can you tell me what you think about it ? I'm not asking anybody to do the work, i'm just looking for a hint or just for somebody to tell me where to start from in js or whatever other language I need to use on the front end.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is certainly possible to split a file via JS into chunks and to senk these ones individually.

1. Declare a file input field:

   ```
   <input type="file" id="input">
   ```
2. Access the first file (there could be more if using the *multiple* attribute):

   ```
   var selected_file = document.getElementById('input').files[0];
   ```
3. You now have a [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) object which also inherits the [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) interface. You can therefore call [Blob.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob.slice) in order to split the data into chunks.
4. Upload those chunks via AJAX
5. Combine the chunks again on the server side

Further readings:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob

Comment: Well this looks rather convenient, and is Set Sail Media right about cross compatibility and the issue this could cause on older browser ? 
Since I'm not too familiar with javascript, would you mind me asking what would happen if a IE8 user  was to try to upload the file, would he just end up in the php flow control or would js trigger an error ?

Comment: @bastienbot Yes, he is right. Older browser do no support the File API (see [here](http://caniuse.com/fileapi) for a comparison table). A customer using such a browser would simply get JS errors ("File: undefined identifier") unless you implement checks whether the File API is supported or not. If you do the latter, the browser will handle the website just as it would contain a normal file input field.

Comment: Thank you very much, this answers perfectly all my questions ! Off I go coding this now, cheers !

Answer (score 1):

The restriction is at the server level.

You MUST adjust your server configuration in order to trickle down to WordPress.

If you set WordPress configuration to a max of 40MB, and Apache (or other web server software) still has a 2MB limit, you won't ever be able to post more than 2MB.

One option would be to use a Flash-based upload tool which can perform some pre-processing to downsize the image before uploading.

If you really want to get fancy, you could develop your own Flash-based upload tool to chunk uploads into 2MB parts (or whatever your server's maximum post size is) and some server-side script to re-assemble the pieces, just like the internet does with packets.

Comment: You do not even need Flash for this task. Any modern browser also supports the File API (cf. my answer).

Comment: Yes, well...this is what I thought could work, so would it work only in Flash or isit possible to split the image in javascript ?

Comment: @ComFreek "Modern browser" translates to "I don't care about my IE7, IE8, IE9 users". Your solution is a good one - but only if the OP isn't developing for any older browser.

Comment: @ComFreek has provided some good information in his answer about a JavaScript-based solution that works in IE10+ and other newer versions of non-IE browsers

Comment: On the other hand Flash solution do not work on mobile platforms, either way, i'll have cross compatibility issues...

Comment: Absolutely right. Just need to choose which part of your population to alienate ;) There will always be some group that isn't supported.